# Baking material used on a model to texture

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, materials, texture-atlas

In my project I have to optimize our assets. I want to create texture atlas. How can I bake objects' materials to a texture, so then I can make all assets in this scene use one material with this texture atlas?

Comment: This is normally done in the 3D Content Creation software where you create your models. What tool are you using for this?

Comment: I use blender and unity. Models weren't made by me. They look to be imported and every different part of it has another material e.g. leaves of a plant green material, flower is red material etc. I want to bake it on a texture, so then I could make a texture atlas out of it and merge these materials. It's my first time doing something like these, so excuse me if my reasoning is inncorrect.

Comment: It looks like [the Blender StackExchange has existing Q&A about how to do this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=bake+materials+atlas). Some recommend this [Material Combiner add-on](https://github.com/Grim-es/material-combiner-addon). Does that give you what you need?